# Understanding wpa_supplicant versus interfaces/interfaces.d

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant

I'm working with embedded devices running Ubuntu 16.04, and trying to configure them to connect to a wireless network through the command line. Nothing too fancy at this stage, networking wise, just connect to a known SSID with a WPA password. I've had some success by configuring `/etc/network/interfaces` directly, by adding appropriate fields (wpa-ssid, wpa-psk, etc) under `iface wlan0 inet static`, but it's been unstable, and my research is indicating this may not be the right way to do this.

The alternative configuration route seems to be using wpa_supplicant, and it's config file, `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Which gets to the heart of my confusion:

What's the relation between configuring `/etc/network/interfaces` (or a file in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`) and configuring `wpa_supplicant.conf`? Are these two alternative methods, or are they interrelated? If they aren't, when would you use one over the other?

Comment: As far as I know, `/etc/network/interfaces` is for configuring network interfaces of various kinds, so it would work for either wireless or ethernet. `wpa_supplicant` is wi-fi specific, probably doesn't work for WPE type of authentication, but don't quote me on that. `/etc/network/interfaces` is also for `ifup` and `ifdown` commands, apparently, but `wpa_supplicant` seems to be a standalone tool.

Comment: If the connection is unstable, it may be the wireless driver. Is it USB or PCI? Please provide details.

Comment: I avoided getting into the details of the configuration since there may be router issues too, and what I'm really hoping for is an explanation of how these linux services interact (or don't), not just getting something running on this specific setup.